# Check if user exists on every request in MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, global-asax

**Hi,**

I need to check if the logged in user do still exists in database, if not I need to redirect to another webpage.

Somthing like this :

```
    if (AccountHandler.Instance.UserIdentityName.Length > 0)
    {
        AccountModel accountModel = new AccountModel();

        if (!accountModel.AccountExists(AccountHandler.Instance.UserIdentityName))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            HttpContext.Current.Items[HttpContextKey.UserContext.ToString()] = null;
            return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery);
        }
    }
```

How do I do this in ASP.NET MVC? I have tried Global.asax Application_BeginRequest but this will be triggered for every request so no redirect should be placed here.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest a global action filter would be the most appropriate way to do this.  An alternative would be to use a base controller with it implemented in OnActionExecuting.

Create a class that derives from ActionFilterAttribute. Add it to the global filters in global.asax.cs.  Have it override OnActionExecuting and implement the code there.

```
public RequireValidUserAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{
     public override void OnActionExecuting( ActionExecutingContext filterContext )
     {
         if (AccountHandler.Instance.UserIdentityName.Length > 0)
         {
             AccountModel accountModel = new AccountModel();

             if (!accountModel.AccountExists(AccountHandler.Instance.UserIdentityName))
             {
                 FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                 filterContext.HttpContext.Items[HttpContextKey.UserContext.ToString()] = null;
                 filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult { Url = Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery };
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Is this possible in MVC2 and if so, how?

Comment: I don't think global filters are available in MVC2. You'd have to go the base controller route there, I think.  It's worth upgrading to MVC3, though, if you can.  Note, it's essentially the same code just implemented in a different place AND you have to remember to derive from the base controller and invoke the base behavior if you override the method in a child controller.